# theme layering codename one

Tags: java, codenameone

Theme layering: I have followed the step given what would be the problem but the  layering is not working. I have changed the purenativetheme constant as false.

```
private Form current;
private Resources theme;

public void init(Object context) {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");
    UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(theme.getTheme("Theme"));
    // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

    // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
    // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
}

public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Welcome", new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE));
    final Label apple = new Label(theme.getImage("apple-icon.png")); 
    final Label android = new Label(theme.getImage("android-icon.png")); 
    final Label windows = new Label(theme.getImage("windows-icon.png")); 
    Button getStarted = new Button("Let's Get Started!");
    getStarted.setUIID("Button");
    FontImage.setMaterialIcon(getStarted, FontImage.MATERIAL_LINK);
    getStarted.setUIID("GetStarted");
    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, 
            LayeredLayout.encloseIn(
                    BoxLayout.encloseY(
                            new Label(theme.getImage("duke-no-logos.png")),
                            getStarted
                    ),
                    FlowLayout.encloseRightMiddle(apple)
                )
    );

    getStarted.addActionListener((e) -> {
        Display.getInstance().execute("https://www.codenameone.com/developers.html");
    });

    new UITimer(() -> {
        if(apple.getParent() != null) {
            apple.getParent().replace(apple, android, CommonTransitions.createFade(500));
        } else {
            if(android.getParent() != null) {
                android.getParent().replace(android, windows, CommonTransitions.createFade(500));
            } else {
                windows.getParent().replace(windows, apple, CommonTransitions.createFade(500));
            }                
        }
    }).schedule(2200, true, hi);
    hi.show();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are just layering the same theme that would have been loaded automatically by initFirstTheme().   Are you layering another theme from the same theme.res file, or a different one?

Comment: i have replaced with                                                                                      theme = UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "Theme 2");
UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(theme.getTheme("Theme 1")); but still not working

Comment: Can you make it clear what you are expecting to happen, vs what does happen?  E.g. How do you know that theme layering is not occurring?

Comment: i set the UIID for the button component and except it to change but it doesn't occurs